# There's no Security.GetChainOfTrustValue when actually there is

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i got this error in unity

```
Assets/Source/LuaWrap/SecurityWrap.cs(113,37): error CS0117: `UnityEngine.Security' does not contain a definition for `GetChainOfTrustValue'
```

this is my code

```
[MonoPInvokeCallbackAttribute(typeof(LuaCSFunction))]
static int GetChainOfTrustValue(IntPtr L)
{
    LuaScriptMgr.CheckArgsCount(L, 1);
    string arg0 = LuaScriptMgr.GetLuaString(L, 1);
    string o = Security.GetChainOfTrustValue(arg0);
    LuaScriptMgr.Push(L, o);
    return 1;
}
```

but actually there IS GetChainOfTrustValue in Security class:

```
namespace UnityEngine
{
    public sealed class Security
    {
        //
        // Static Methods
        //
        [SecuritySafeCritical]
        public static string GetChainOfTrustValue (string name)
        {
            ...
```

how is this happening?

Comment: Does it work in the editor? Does it work if you change build types? (I found a similar issue where webgl wont build if you have HLAPI package installed) but its fine in editor

Comment: yes it works fine in the editor it wont built to android apk @BugFinder

Comment: Webplayer security related class. Not supported from 5.4.0 onwards.

Comment: @shingo but i'm using unity 4.6.9, what should I do?

Comment: Webplayer is already deprecated long time ago, you may consider migrating to webgl.

Comment: upgrade to a more recent version of unity? 4.6.9 came out 3.5 years ago.